# Does assigning values to model saves the model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In the codebase in a controller I saw

```
def destroy
  @workflow_automation.status = WorkflowAutomation::STATUS[:deleted]
  render_workflows
end
```

and that's it, no save. It works most of the time but I'm trying to debug an issue where the change didn't happen. Can it be a reason for that? Why is this intermittent?

Comment: If there is an implicit `save` when assigning a value to `status` totally depends on the implementation of the `status=` method. It can be a simple assignment, it can be an extremely complex method that updates and saves multiple objects. Only someone with access to the source code of that method is able to answer your question.

Comment: If a `save` call would be missing it wouldn't work _"most of the time"_, so apparently, something else is going on. Maybe `status=` was overridden, maybe due to a gem. There could also be a callback that saves the record. You could hook into the model's save-[callbacks](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html) to see where it is called from.

Answer (score -1):

It is not saved, if you are using enum you need to use bang method, like:

`@workflow_automation.deleted!`

then it will auto save to model